# Filter in Angular.js by checking against a scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm trying to get a certain object out of an array of objects, that meets a certain criteria.

The id of the object should equal the scope variable `$scope.lobbyid`. My current approach below does not pass the lobby object into the controller.

the selected `lobby` represents the data of the active tab on the site. so the container array is fetched only once on site load.

markup

```
<div ng-repeat="lobby in lobbies | filter:checkLobbyID(lobby)">
    [[lobby.name]]
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.checkLobbyID = function($lobby) {
    return $lobby.lobbyid == $scope.lobbyid;
}
```

array

```
"lobbies": [
    {
        "isglobal": true,
        "lobbyid": 1,
        "name": "GLOBAL",
    },
    {
        "isglobal": false,
        "lobbyid": 2,
        "name": "stackoverflow rules",
    },
    {
        "isglobal": false,
        "lobbyid": 3,
        "name": "sdadadad",
    }
]
```

a temporary solution is to add the following code to the tab-switch event. but this needs a copy and another scope variable. how to achieve this with a filter?

```
angular.forEach($scope.lobbies, function(lobby) {
    if (lobby.lobbyid == $scope.lobbyid)
    $scope.currLobby = angular.copy(lobby);
});
```

Comment: If you are trying to get a single object, why are you using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: the scope value changes quite often and i want the markup to get the object with the right id automatically. i guess you suppose to create another copy of the object into another scope variable, when updating the array?

Comment: Angular two-way-bindings work constantly and in real time, do they not?

Comment: i edited my post. i need to tab through the array of lobbies depending on the current selected id, which is stored at $scope.lobbyid

Comment: please creat a demo in plunker that gives overview of what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 6):

You dont need the lobby param in the markup. the filter will implicitly pass it to the scope-filter function

```
<div ng-repeat="lobby in lobbies | filter:checkLobbyID">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vrwQG/

regards

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: any idea how to pass a param for the checkLobbyID call?